# How to show calendar view in application?

Tags: android, calendar

Can anyone tell me how to use calendar view in application?

I want to get number of days selected by user and also need to get option to select multiple days.

Comment: show wat u tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Android does not offer any calendar view in the SDK.so developer can import and use CalendarView to display a specified date in a month view, or let user pick up a date from it. try this link here is a demo of calender view

http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/